# test_func for UserPassesTestMixin with get_object does not work with ListView

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

in the contacts section of the dashboard of my projects, saved contacts are only visible to the author but previously they are visible to everyone because I forgot to include `UserPassesTestMixin` in CBV. I included but browser showed me the error named NotImplemented test_func, I also implemented test_func

**views.py**

```
class ContactListView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, ListView):
   model = ClientContact
   template_name = 'site/contacts.html'
   context_object_name = 'contacts'
   ordering = ['created_at', '-updated_at']

   def test_func(self):
       contact = self.get_object()
       if self.request.user == contact.author:
          return True
       return False
```

it says again NotImplemented test_func, as well as get_oject, is an unresolved ref in ListView
I am sure I am doing something wrong but I cannot find my mistake. Please if anyone who knows this, correct me! Thank you

Comment: When you ask questions about errors, please show the full traceback - it makes it much clearer where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListView` is for displaying multiple objects, so it doesn't make sense to call `get_object()` (which is for views for a single object like `DetailView`).

The usual approach for list views is to override `get_queryset`, and filter the queryset to only show that user's objects.

```
class ContactListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = ClientContact
    template_name = 'site/contacts.html'
    context_object_name = 'contacts'
    ordering = ['created_at', '-updated_at']

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ContactListView, self).get_queryset().filter(author=self.request.user)
```

You already have `LoginRequiredMixin`, which will handle the case when the user is not logged-in.

If you wanted to filter the queryset in multiple list views, you could write a mixin, for example:

```
class AuthorMixin(object):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(AuthorMixin, self).get_queryset().filter(author=self.request.user)
```

Then use it in your view as:

```
class ContactListView(LoginRequiredMixin, AuthorMixin, ListView):
    ...
```

Note that the above is untested, it requires `LoginRequiredMixin` (because it doesn't handle the anonymous user case), and it will only work if the user foreign key is named `author`. You could improve the mixin, but you might prefer to repeat the `get_queryset` method.

Comment: thanks @Alasdair it finally works. I am going to ask couple of question  because I am new to django for every object should i write this queryset or can I paste it into file and call it? and in my project there is one more step after user registration called "click to finish" where users can complete their profile. When user is created it redirects to dashborad it should automatically redirct profile complete page i delayed to do this because it took much time from. That's why can give me idea about these please if you do not mind?

Comment: If you wanted to reuse code in class based views, the correct approach is to use a mixin. I've added a simple example above. Your question about user creation sounds like a separate issue so I can't help with that.